# Why I cannot see all the options under "new" menu in Android studio 3.3

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.3

Recently I updated Android Studio. After the update I cannot find all the options under the "new" menu. Please check my screenshot. Previously there were many options like I can create empty activity, Java class from there. How can I get those options back?

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio with New context menu open]

Comment: Which version of android studio exactly? 3.3.1 or 3.3.2?